# Align item inside block displayed with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to display list `(ul li)`

There is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMVGdq) or snippet below to show my code & issue.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: small;
}

h1 {
  font-size: small;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  font-size: 12px;
}

li {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}

.ul-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<h1>Standard code</h1>
<div>
  <ul class="ul-container">
    <li>
      <div class="description">
        <h2>Block 1</h2>
        <p>Text 1<br/>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="description">
        <h2>Block 2</h2>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2<br/>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="description">
        <h2>Block 3</h2>
        <p>Text 1</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1>Expected result</h1>
<p> 'br' have been forced to demonstrate the expected behaviour ('Text1 - block 1' and 'Text2 - block 2' have 2 lines)
  <div>
    <ul class="ul-container">
      <li>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Block 1</h2>
          <p>Text 1<br/>Text 1</p>
          <p>Text 2<br/>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Block 2</h2>
          <p>Text 1<br/>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Text 2<br/>Text 2</p>
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Block 3</h2>
          <p>Text 1<br/>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Text 2<br/>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Or ('Text2 - Block 2' have 2 lines)</p>
  <div>
    <ul class="ul-container">
      <li>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Block 1</h2>
          <p>Text 1</p>
          <p>Text 2<br/>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Block 2</h2>
          <p>Text 1</p>
          <p>Text 2<br/>Text 2</p>
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div class="description">
          <h2>Block 3</h2>
          <p>Text 1</p>
          <p>Text 2<br/>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I would like to align paragraph inside a list item, dynamically depending on the content (and size of each paragraph), is there a way to achieve that with pure CSS?

Thanks,

[image: Expected behaviour]

Comment: Sure, here it is.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMVGdq

Comment: This is not possible with flexbox. Consider CSS-Grid instead. Flexbox has **no** mechanism for aligning elements that do not share a parent. Likely this is not possible with Grid either though without a change in the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use `display: felxbox` to make a grid. Just use `display: grid` and you'll have the expected result.

The general rule is:

- `flexbox` is for aligning items and flexible layouts
- `grid` is for consistent two dimensional (grid) layouts

You can find a good how to [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Sorry but I don't agree with your general rules .. flexbox and grid are both used for layout and for alignment.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: You are right, I was writing only for this specific example. In other cases `flexbox` is more viable.